# Make a virtual function that returns a generic member function pointer

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, c++14, type-erasure

I want to write an abstract class named `COMMUNICATOR` that has a virtual function `get_func()`.

```
class COMMUNICATOR : public QObject{
public:
    virtual <what type???> get_func() = 0;
};
```

Now suppose `INT_SENDER`, `INT_RECEIVER`, `STR_SENDER`, and `STR_RECEIVER` all derive from `COMMUNICATOR`. They each provide their own implementation of get_func(),  and they can be used like this:

```
COMMUNICATOR *int_sender = new INT_SENDER;
COMMUNICATOR *int_receiver = new INT_RECEIVER;

COMMUNICATOR *str_sender = new STR_SENDER;
COMMUNICATOR *str_receiver = new STR_RECEIVER;

//INT_SENDER::get_func() and INT_RECEIVER::get_func() both return a member function pointer of signature void(*)(int)
connect( int_sender, int_sender->get_func(), int_receiver, int_receiver->get_func() );

//STR_SENDER::get_func() and STR_RECEIVER::get_func() both return a member function pointer of signature void(*)(std::string)
connect( str_sender, str_sender->get_func(), str_receiver, str_receiver->get_func() );
```

What I want to achieve with this design are:

(1) To give all classes that derive from COMMUNICATOR the same interface: the get_func() function

(2) Using COMMUNICATOR and its derived classes does not require dealing with the signature of the function returned by get_func(). Instead, the function pointers are passed directly into connect();

Is there some sort of hack to achieve what I want, like  making get_func() return some type-erasing wrapper object from which I can dump a function pointer into connect()? Or am I attempting the impossible here?

Comment: return type is part of the function signature, if you want to use overriding, you need to provide a common base for all return types

Comment: This looks like an awfully wrong way to say something simple, like `sender.connect(receiver)`.

Comment: Try to use NVI Idom (Non-Virtual Interface) : make get_func public which calls a privated virtual one and override that latter in each derived subclass.

Comment: More to the point,  why should functions returned by get_func have different signatures? Can you illustrate, with a (pseudo)code example, the importance of having different signatures?

Comment: @n.m. I want to avoid using the original Qt syntax QObject::connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::valueChanged). I want to hide the specific functions that are being exported for Qt connection, and instead let sender and receiver decide which functions they want to export for connection, like this: QObject::connect( sender, sender->get_func(), receiver, receiver->get_func() )

Comment: My advice is don't do that. Perhaos you want to think why Qt interface looks like it does, and not like what you envision. Hint: it's not because Qt people are insufficiently versed in OOP. Do you have Java backround per any chance?

Comment: I have been asked to write a CONNECTOR class which, given any two COMMUNICATOR objects, can make a Qt connection between them without knowing the internals of these objects. When a CONNECTOR object is connecting two COMMUNICATOR objects, it cannot see inside the COMMUNICATOR objects, hence the COMMUNICATOR objects need to export the functions that need to be connected, which is why I want to have a get_func() interface in the COMMUNICATOR class.

Comment: Sorry for the all-uppercase naming, it's just a convention that the company I'm working at requires.

Comment: I think qt connect function needs to know about the declaration of the functions (signal, slot and it params ) in order to connect them together. There is a moc program ran after to analyze all connect function then generate the real 'connect' codes.

Comment: So your company doesn't understand the Qt technology and suffers from NIH syndrome. My sympathy is with you.